# JavaScript async & defer: run a script asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

As far as I am aware, in the `script` element, the `async` attribute allows the script to download asynchronously (similar to images), while the `defer` causes the script to wait until the end before executing.

Suppose I have two scripts to include:

```
<script src="library.js"></script>
<script src="process.js"></script>
```

I would want them both to proceed asynchronously, and I would want `process.js` to wait until the end to start processing.

Is there a way to get the `library.js` script to *run* asynchronously?

**Note**

I see there appears to be some discrepancy between different online resources as to the actual role of the `async` attribute.

MDN & WhatWG suggest that it means that the script should *execute* asynchronously. Other online resources suggest that it should *load* asynchronously, but still blocks rendering when it is executed.

Comment: So you want `library.js` to finish running before `process.js` starts?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Good point. Yes, I would expect `process.js` to have access to the library.

Comment: @Phil I had a look at that link, and I normally regard MDN as authoritative. However, other sites I have looked at definitely suggest that `async` refers to _loading_ the script.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I removed the comment :)

Comment: @Phil. Pity. I see that the __whatwg.org__ standard also refers to _executing_ the script … this is getting a little confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I found [Sequential script loading in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@asimmittal/sequential-script-loading-in-javascript-a0b77ca9467c) which might help you:

```js
(function(){
  
  //three JS files that need to be loaded one after the other
  var libs = [
    'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.string/3.3.4/underscore.string.js'
  ];
  
  var injectLibFromStack = function(){
      if(libs.length > 0){
        
        //grab the next item on the stack
        var nextLib = libs.shift();
        var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        
        //create a script tag with this library
        var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
        scriptTag.src = nextLib;
        
        //when successful, inject the next script
        scriptTag.onload = function(e){
          console.log("---> loaded: " + e.target.src);
          injectLibFromStack();
        };    
        
        //append the script tag to the <head></head>
        headTag.appendChild(scriptTag);
        console.log("injecting: " + nextLib);
      }
      else return;
  }
  
  //start script injection
  injectLibFromStack();
})();
```

Comment: So the key is that the `load` event is fired by the `<script>` element when all of the script's synchronous actions are complete, cool

Comment: Not really. The question was about the `async` and `defer` attributes. MDN states that scripts inserted using `document.createElement`, as in the sample above, are executed asynchronously by default.

Answer (score 1):

Both `defer` and `async` affect when a script is executed, not when a script is downloaded. I think the confusion comes from the fact that some documentation is a bit sloppy with terms, and the term *loaded* is unclear as to whether it refers to the fetching of the resource, or the execution of it.

To get `library.js` to run asyncronously without waiting for the document to load, use `async` attribute, and to get `process.js` to wait until document has been parsed, use `defer`:

```
<script src="library.js" async></script>
<script src="process.js" defer></script>
```

Note that `library.js` is not guaranteed to run before `process.js`, although it probably will.

Comment: I have had a look at the WhatWG Specs, and raised an issue regarding the ambiguity. It appears that `async` _loads_ the script asynchronously, but still _executes_ synchronously.